# Save microphone and audio out volume levels in PulseAudio to a file that can be restored from

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, volume-control

I have to fiddle around far too often to use Skype, and it's not clearly Skype's fault.
I want to work around the problem by saving the audio level settings to disk and restoring them.

Please tell me this is possible :D

Comment: Using alsactl store to save audio settings could solve this problem, but I haven't tested it yet!

Comment: See this answer if it does work?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/129460/workaround-for-volume-settings-going-to-maximum-after-reboot/206528#206528

Answer (score 1):

I think these two commands should work:

```
alsactl store
```

(to save the state to the default config file), and later:

```
alsactl restore
```