# Where is Start-up Applications in 14.04 Unity?

Tags: 14.04, unity, autostart

I cannot find the Start-up Applications in 14.04, I read on a forum that you had to go into Main Menu and allow it to be visible through preferences, but I have looked all the way through preferences and I still haven't found it????

Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Easiest method is to search for "start" in dash:

[image]

It is also possible to start it from command line, the command is `gnome-session-properties`:

[image]

Comment: @mchid mine still shows it when searching. Are you sure you are using Ubuntu with Unity?

Comment: reinstalled ubuntu-desktop and now it's there

Comment: It is possible that dash does not show it because of localization. You can always launch it from the dash with `gnome-session-properties` anyway, or try searching for 'startup' in your native language.

Comment: Please explain the downvote :(