# Loading services and apps on reboot

Tags: plex

When my Windows media PC reboots I have to log back in to get Plex and Playon to run.

If the Ubuntu PC reboots do I have to log back in or will these programs automatically load if designated in startup?

Comment: You can manage startup applications: http://askubuntu.com/a/452663/32103