# How do I PERMANENTLY add gain to front center audio track only?

Tags: sound, video, pulseaudio, dialog

After YEARS of not being able to find an answer as to why certain videos had background music drowning out voices, I finally got an answer, kinda.  For reasons that I have long since given up on solving, audio that's more than 2 channels is not downmixed properly, across clean installs of every version since 10.04.  Simple fix was to install Pulseaudio control panel, and boost Front Center by about 30%.  BUT!  I have to do that EVERY TIME.  It's really annoying. I'm not that good with editing code and all that, but even if it constantly resets the volume to 100% (and 130% for front) every time, is there a way to make that ratio the default?  Even if I make a playlist, it sometimes resets between episodes, sometimes it does not.  Sometimes if I close VLC and restart the same video, the change in front volume will still be there, sometimes it won't.  So I know there is some ability to retain the setting in there somewhere.  Please help, thanks.

Comment: Looking for same answers from https://askubuntu.com/questions/129460/workaround-for-volume-settings-going-to-maximum-after-reboot/ , may be a duplicate?